# Chrome extension google.payments.inapp.getPurchases fail

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, in-app-purchase, chrome-web-store

my chrome extension is implementing the google in-app payment flow to add features.  currently both getSkuDetails() and buy() are working.  for some reason the getPurchases method is always hitting the failure method.  In my manifest.js I have the 'buy.js' script in my "web_accessible_resourses" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly" in permissions >> oauth2 >> scopes.

as a troubleshooting step, I went through the "buy()" flow and actually purchased the app to make sure the default response was not to hit the failure method.  The extension is still hitting the failure method even after purchase.

very confused as to why "getSkuDetails" and "buy()" are working but getPurchases() is not.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own issue.  you have to include the 'parameters': {'env': 'prod'} parameter along with the success and failure methods even though it is not specified in the docs.